# Navigation IllegalArgumentException cannot be found from the current destination

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation, android-navigation-graph

Get next error:

```
Non-fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation action/destination com.sai.mand:id/bottom_menu_dialog cannot be found from the current destination a(com.sai.mand:id/bottomMenuDialog) label=BottomMenuDialog
       at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:931)
       at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:868)
       at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:854)
       at com.sai.mand.tools.NavigationHelperKt.startMailApp(NavigationHelperKt.java:131)
       at com.sai.mand.features.authorizations.list.AuthorizationsListFragment$setupViewModel$5.onChanged(AuthorizationsListFragment.java:144)
       at com.sai.mand.features.authorizations.list.AuthorizationsListFragment$setupViewModel$5.onChanged(AuthorizationsListFragment.java:51)
       at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.considerNotify(LiveData.java:131)
       at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.dispatchingValue(LiveData.java:149)
       at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.setValue(LiveData.java:307)
       at androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData.setValue(MutableLiveData.java:50)
       at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData$1.run(LiveData.java:91)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7050)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
```

But I don't understand why he swears that he can't find `bottom_menu_dialog`, when in the error itself he refers to the `fun startMailApp` if I correctly understood the essence of the problem.

But anyway here is the code of my startMailApp:

```
fun FragmentActivity.startMailApp(supportEmail: String? = null) {
    try {
        this.startActivityForResult(Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO)
            .apply { data = Uri.parse("mailto:${supportEmail ?: DEFAULT_SUPPORT_EMAIL_LINK}") }, 0
        )
    } catch (ignored: IllegalStateException) {
    } catch (ignored: ActivityNotFoundException) {
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Timber.e(e)
    }
}
```

And code of `nav_graph` and how it is used:

```
<dialog
    android:id="@+id/bottomMenuDialog"
    android:name="com.sai.mand.features.menu.BottomMenuDialog"
    android:label="BottomMenuDialog" />

    viewModel.onMoreMenuClickEvent.observe(this, Observer { event ->
        event.getContentIfNotHandled()?.let { menuItems ->
            navigateToDialog(R.id.bottom_menu_dialog, menuItems)
        }
    })

fun Fragment.navigateToDialog(actionRes: ResId, bundle: Bundle) {
    try {
        findNavController().navigate(actionRes, bundle)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Timber.e(e)
    }
}
```